# If cookie exists read and set it's value to a variable in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, woocommerce

I've created two custom functions in my Woocommerce store. The idea is to limit a certain type of product to a maximum of 3. I want to set a cookie for one week to prevent more of the same type of product being purchased by the same customer. So if the customer buys 1 today, then for the next 6 days they could still purchase up to another 2 until the cookie expires. But 3 would always be the maximum.

The function works in that it will set a limit if more than 3 items are added to the basket in one session, and the cookie still exists after checkout. My hunch is it's not being read at the right time, or passed to the function which checks if it exists.

```
    function filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation( $true, $product_id, $request_quantity, $variation_id = '', $request_variation = '' ) {
        // holds checks for all products in cart to see if they're in our category
        $lpc_cookie = $_COOKIE['lpc'];

        if ( isset( $lpc_cookie ) ) {
            $category_checks = $lpc_cookie;
        } else {
            $category_checks = 0;
        }

        $limited_product_count = 4;
        $limited_slug = 'instant-print'; //replace 'instant-print' with your category's slug

        // check each cart item for our category
        if( ! is_admin() ) {
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                $product = $cart_item['data'];

                if ( has_term( $limited_slug, 'product_cat', $product->id ) ) {
                    $category_checks += $cart_item['quantity'];
                }
            }
        }

        // We also check the item that the user is trying to add to cart
        if ( has_term( $limited_slug, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            $category_checks += $request_quantity;
        }

        if ($category_checks >= $limited_product_count) {
            $notice = 'Sorry, you have reached the maximum amount for this type of product that you can purchase during this period.';
            wc_add_notice( __( $notice, 'textdomain' ), 'error' );
            return false;
        }

        return $true;
    };

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 3 );

    function set_cookie_for_limited_products () {
        $limited_slug = 'instant-print'; //replace 'instant-print' with your category's slug
        // check each cart item for our category
        if( ! is_admin() ) {
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                $product = $cart_item['data'];

                if ( has_term( $limited_slug, 'product_cat', $product->id ) ) {
                    $category_checks += $cart_item['quantity'];
                }
            }
        }

        // $expire = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7; // expires in one week
        $expire = time() + 60 * 60; // expires in one hour
        setcookie('lpc', $category_checks, $expire);
    }

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'set_cookie_for_limited_products' );
```

I hope this is something obvious. Initially I was trying to echo and var_dump variables, but I found that was causing other stuff to break.

Comment: Why put this in cookies ??? what about if the user decide just to open an other browser or use the "New Private window" ? why not insert in a DB the purchases related to the user, and check if user purchased via DB query....

Comment: @lharby The customer must be registered in the store? If so, you should implement that this is stored with the user, if you force the client to be registered, I can help you, using cookies is not a good idea

Comment: @DanielRiera this is my current setup, https://imgur.com/m5DAs0G so you are saying I should disable guest checkout? I don't want to put people off ordering. I know that cookies are flawed but I also don't know how to read or write any db queries.

Comment: @lharby check my answer :)

Comment: Oh I prefer the idea of using both options. I will try and check this later and get back to you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, I can give you an example, but if guests can make purchases, you won't be able to save that information, it's an example that takes into account the two possible situations.

```php
function filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation( $true, $product_id, $request_quantity, $variation_id = '', $request_variation = '' ) {
        // holds checks for all products in cart to see if they're in our category

        $limited_product_count = 4;
        $limited_slug = 'instant-print'; //replace 'instant-print' with your category's slug

        if(is_user_logged_in()) {
            //Using database
            $user_id = get_current_user_id();
            $lpc_cookie = get_user_meta( $user_id, $limited_slug, true );
            $expire = get_user_meta( $user_id, $limited_slug . '_expire', true );
        }else{
            //Using cookie
            $lpc_cookie = $_COOKIE['lpc'];
        }

        //Check lpc_cookie and expire value
        if ( isset( $lpc_cookie ) && $expire > time() ) {
            $category_checks = $lpc_cookie;
        } else {
            $category_checks = 0;
        }

        

        // check each cart item for our category
        if( ! is_admin() ) {
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                $product = $cart_item['data'];

                if ( has_term( $limited_slug, 'product_cat', $product->id ) ) {
                    $category_checks += $cart_item['quantity'];
                }
            }
        }

        // We also check the item that the user is trying to add to cart
        if ( has_term( $limited_slug, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            $category_checks += $request_quantity;
        }

        if ($category_checks >= $limited_product_count) {
            $notice = 'Sorry, you have reached the maximum amount for this type of product that you can purchase during this period.';
            wc_add_notice( __( $notice, 'textdomain' ), 'error' );
            return false;
        }

        return $true;
    };

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 3 );

    function set_cookie_for_limited_products () {
        $limited_slug = 'instant-print'; //replace 'instant-print' with your category's slug
        // check each cart item for our category
        if( ! is_admin() ) {
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                $product = $cart_item['data'];

                if ( has_term( $limited_slug, 'product_cat', $product->id ) ) {
                    $category_checks += $cart_item['quantity'];
                }
            }
        }

        // $expire = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7; // expires in one week
        $expire = time() + 60 * 60; // expires in one hour

        if(is_user_logged_in()) {
            //Using database
            $user_id = get_current_user_id();
            update_user_meta( $user_id, $limited_slug, $category_checks );
            update_user_meta( $user_id, $limited_slug . '_expire', $expire );
        }else{
            //Using cookie
            setcookie('lpc', $category_checks, $expire);
        }
    }

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'set_cookie_for_limited_products' );
```

Comment: Hmm, this is the direction I want to go in. My issue is the same as above. To replicate it, I signed out of WP. Purchased two items and checked out. Then came back to a new session. In my mind this means now I can only add 1 more item from the limited category to my cart, as the cookie (or the get_user_meta) should be set to 2, but it is not being read on the store pages. So this is never being set `$category_checks = $lpc_cookie;` and I don't know how to solve that, also testing this seems to be quite difficult.

Comment: Maybe I need a different function than `filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` in order to check if the cookie/db value exists across all store pages (although to my mind this should be enough right)

Comment: Check your database if prefix_usermeta exist  instant-print meta_key on your user ID

Comment: Yes it does exist, see https://imgur.com/0SOXvwU but either way it's not being passed to `$category_checks` via db value or cookie value.

Comment: Hmm, I may have logged out at this point and then gone through checkout using the cookie method, but I would have expected this to be set via one method or the other. And on a new session it would let me add another 3 products to the basket despite db and/or cookie being set. I was going to suggest continuing in a chat but I don't seem to have that option. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/?tab=site&host=stackoverflow.com

Comment: Is possible synchronize $_COOKIES <-> DATABASE... but i need time :) where talk about this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229555/discussion-between-lharby-and-daniel-riera).